# Clothes combination HTML app. Insights please

Tags: jquery, html, flash

I have to create an app that combines different colors and accesories that user must choose.

Example :

The same shirt can be chosen by the user in 10 colors and combine with 10 colors of buttons and 20 possible accesories.

I have no problem in creating all 10 colors with 10 buttons colors each, but accesories must be "mountable" on the picture.

i can do this in flash very easily but I'd like to use HTML to improve compatibility and size.

Could you please give me some advice?

thansk

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit too broad, but look into [jQueryUI's draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)-component which you can easily use to make the clothes "mountable". Otherwise the process is pretty much the same as in Flash/AS3

Comment: Thanks, that is more advance that my needs. I need a menu with 6 clothes pictures (cloth with buttons) and 10+ colors for the main cloth and 5+ colors for the buttons. Then you click a model , and after that you click a color and the app combines it. I dont know a simplier way to solve the problem of the combinations than photoshopping every cloth color/buttons color. Maybe with the comp you sent me I can simplify all :) thanks